# Select the Max row number for an account

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I need to only pull the max row number for an account. I know it's a grouping issue.

Current data:

| ACCOUNT_UID | ID | NAME | ACADEMIC_PERIOD | CAT_BY_DATE | CAT_DATE | MAX_ROW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | abc | Popeye | 202190 | CPT | 9/15/2021 | 1 |
| abc | abc | Popeye | 202190 | CSH | 10/4/2021 | 2 |

I only need the second row.

Current query:

```
Select
A.ACCOUNT_UID,
A.ID,
A.NAME,
A.ACADEMIC_PERIOD,
A.cat_by_date,
A.Cat_date,
Max (A.row_num) max_row

From
(select RAD.ACCOUNT_UID,
RAD.ID,
RAD.NAME,
RAD.ACADEMIC_PERIOD,
listagg(RAD.CATEGORY, ', ') within group (order by RAD.CATEGORY) as cat_by_date,
trunc(RAD.TRANSACTION_DATE) as Cat_date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by RAD.ACCOUNT_UID ORDER BY trunc(RAD.TRANSACTION_DATE))  as 
row_num

from RAD
where RAD.ACADEMIC_PERIOD ='202190'
and RAD.CATEGORY in ('CPT', 'CSH')

group by
RAD.ACCOUNT_UID,
RAD.ID,
RAD.NAME,
RAD.ACADEMIC_PERIOD,
trunc(RAD.TRANSACTION_DATE)
order by 1 ) A

group by
A.ACCOUNT_UID,
A.ID,
A.NAME,
A.ACADEMIC_PERIOD
A.cat_by_date,
A.Cat_date

Order by 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```sql
Select
  A.ACCOUNT_UID,
  A.ID,
  A.NAME,
  A.ACADEMIC_PERIOD,
  A.cat_by_date,
  A.Cat_date
From
  (select RAD.ACCOUNT_UID,
          RAD.ID,
          RAD.NAME,
          RAD.ACADEMIC_PERIOD,
          listagg(RAD.CATEGORY, ', ') within group (order by RAD.CATEGORY) as cat_by_date,
          trunc(RAD.TRANSACTION_DATE) as Cat_date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by RAD.ACCOUNT_UID ORDER BY trunc(RAD.TRANSACTION_DATE) DESC)  as rn
     from RAD
    where RAD.ACADEMIC_PERIOD ='202190'
      and RAD.CATEGORY in ('CPT', 'CSH')
    group by
          RAD.ACCOUNT_UID,
          RAD.ID,
          RAD.NAME,
          RAD.ACADEMIC_PERIOD,
          trunc(RAD.TRANSACTION_DATE)
    order by 1 ) A
Where A.rn = 1
Order by 1
```

The idea is to apply the `row_number` window function in descending order of `transaction_date` per every `account_uid` and pick the first row obtained.